# How to use optimisticResponse in Apollo Angular with refetchQueries

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to utilize Apollo's Optimistic UI but I can't get it to work as expected. To test it I've set up a breakpoint on the server so the response can be stalled. I would expect to see mutation result in changes in the list, but the whole thing waits for the response from the server. What am I doing wrong?

This is Angular 7, Apollo-angular client 2.4.0 for Angular:

```
"apollo-angular": "^1.5.0",
    "apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.6.0",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.3.2",
    "apollo-client": "^2.4.0",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.11",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.10",
```

To see if the item is in the cache I've called this first and it returns an ID as expected:

```
let testID = defaultDataIdFromObject(mail); 
console.log('found in cache: ', testID); // outputs the correct ID 
(e.g. found in cache)
```

Console output:

> Email:Cl4weDliM2QyZjQ1OTU2ZTZlMmZmOTAyMjRkYTkxNmE2MjI1ZDk2NWM3MDcAAAFrAUPhyTB4OWIzZDJmNDU5NTZlNmUyZmY5MDIyNGRhOTE2YTYyMjVkOTY1YzcwNzVB

This is the complete query:

```
this.trashEmailGQL.mutate({
      id: mail.id,
      table: Table.ARCHIVE
    },{
      refetchQueries: [{
        query: this.getEmailsGQL.document,
        variables: {table: Table.ARCHIVE}
      },
      {
        query: this.getEmailsGQL.document,
        variables: {table: Table.TRASH}
      }],
      optimisticResponse:{
        __typename:'Mutation',
        trashEmail:{
          __typename:"Email",
          id:mail.id,
          fromEmail:mail.fromEmail,
          fromName:mail.fromName,
          fromAddress:mail.fromAddress,
          cc: mail.cc,
          bcc: [],
          replyTo:mail.replyTo,
          body:mail.body,
          contentType:mail.contentType,
          draftId:"",
          read:mail.read,
          inReplyTo:mail.inReplyTo,
          inReferences:mail.inReferences,
          created:mail.created
        }
      }
    }).subscribe(({data}) => {
      console.log('Trashed email response: ', data);
    }, (err) => {
      this.errorService.handleError(err);
    });
```

I would expect that Apollo would return results from the cache and update the table before the server returns any response.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Apollo 2.x doesn't support delete mutations out of the box. So manual deletion from cache needs to be performed. The solution doesn't look too good (code explosion) but it's currently better than having a rock thrown in your back.

Supposedly version 3.x should address this issue but currently, this is the solution I found works one would expect.

```
this.trashEmailGQL.mutate({
      id: mail.id,
      table: Table.ARCHIVE
    },  
    {
        refetchQueries: [{
          query: this.getEmailsGQL.document,
          variables: {table: Table.ARCHIVE}
        },
        {
          query: this.getEmailsGQL.document,
          variables: {table: Table.TRASH}
        }], 
        optimisticResponse:{
          __typename:'Mutation',
          trashEmail:{
            __typename:"Email",
            id:mail.id,
            fromEmail:mail.fromEmail,
            fromName:mail.fromName,
            fromAddress:mail.fromAddress,
            cc: mail.cc,
            bcc: [],
            replyTo:mail.replyTo,
            body:mail.body,
            contentType:mail.contentType,
            draftId:"",
            read:mail.read,
            inReplyTo:mail.inReplyTo,
            inReferences:mail.inReferences,
            created:mail.created
          }
        },
        update: (store, {data :{trashedEmail}}) => {
          const data = store.readQuery({query: this.getEmailsGQL.document, variables: {table: Table.ARCHIVE}});
          if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('getEmails')) {
            let cacheList:Email[] = data['getEmails'];
            let foundItemIndex = cacheList.findIndex(i => i.id === mail.id);
            if (foundItemIndex > -1) {
              cacheList.splice(foundItemIndex,1)
              data['getEmails'] = cacheList
              store.writeQuery({query: this.getEmailsGQL.document, variables: {table: Table.ARCHIVE}, data:data});
            }
          }
        }
      }
     ).subscribe(({data}) => {
      console.log('Trashed email response: ', data);
    }, (err) => {
      this.errorService.handleError(err);
    });
```